# Great difficulty setting up Ajax Push Engine(APE) in my Virtual Box

Tags: ajax, push, ape

Is there any kind fellow windows user who had faced similar problems that can provide me some concrete ways in setting up the APE?

Answer (score 1):

From their homepage: http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Setup

Also from their google group: http://groups.google.com/group/ape-project/web/installing-ape-on-ubuntu-9-04

The second is specific to ubuntu 9.04 so fi you are using virtual box you could install ubuntu 9.04 and go through this guide.